# What is the time complexity of truncated SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Full SVD, on an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, `[U,S,V] = svd(A)`, would cost $O(m^2n + mn^2 + n^3)$ time. But what is the time complexity if we only need the $k$ largest singular values, say, `[U_k,S_k,V_k] = svds(A,k)`?

Comment: Can you add a reference for your bound? I presume that bound is for the zero-error SVD? Are you only interested in that case? Do you care about the bit-size of the entries and condition numbers?

Comment: Your title says *approximated*, but your question text doesn't.

Answer (score 22):

@ user40484 , fortunately your estimate for the complexity of SVD is not optimal. Otherwise, you put unemployed specialists in image compression. The complexity is in $O(\min(mn^2,m^2n))$.

Assume the data points are in the columns of $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ where $m\leq n$. Note that  $AA^T$ is the dataset covariance matrix. Then a simple method is to randomly choose $k<m$ columns of $A$ that form a matrix $S$. Statistically, the SVD of $SS^T$ will be close to that of $AA^T$; thus it suffices to calculate the SVD of $S$, the complexity of which, is only $O(k^2m)$.

EDIT. Answer to Michael.

Let $A\in M_{m,n}$ where $m\geq n$ (otherwise change $A$ into $A^T$.

In "matrix computations", Golub-Van loan  gave $O(m^2n)$ as complexity for the svd. The authors calculate $A^TA$ with complexity $nm^2$ and its eigenvalues with complexity $\approx 20n^3$... Non-tiring work.

The good idea is to find the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ without computing $A^TA$.

First step. Reduce $A$ into a $n\times n$ bidiagonal matrix $B$.

Second step. Compute the singular values and vectors of $B$.

This method has complexity $O(mn^2)$.

Reference for the method

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf

I have no reference for the calculation of its complexity.

Comment: What assumptions does this make on the columns of A? What if some columns of A are very dense or have a large norm, while others are sparse?

Comment: You are right. If there is a too great disparity between the columns, then the approximation may be bad. In such cases, we must increase k

Comment: @AlexWilliams To prevent those problems, the norm of the columns is taken into account to draw them from a biased distribution and they are scaled before forming matrix $S$.

Comment: Isn't this in contradiction to what is written in this `sklearn` documentation on PCA?: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#pca-using-randomized-svd it says complexity of PCA (which allegedly uses SVD internally) is $O(n_{max}^2n_{min})$. Yours says the opposite: $O(n_{min}^2 n_{max})$.

Comment: @Michael cf. my edit.

Comment: @loupblanc Thank you for the update. I do not doubt your answer. I am just confused that `sklearn` -- a widely used package -- report the wrong complexity.

Comment: Can anyone comment on why the SVD of S is similar to that of A? As far as I can tell, they are not only different but incomparable (the right singular vectors have different sizes for A and S). And even the singular values themselves are very different when I generate random matrix. Do I misunderstand that you suggest to just take the SVD of S and use it as an approximation of the SVD of A or is there more to it?

Comment: @Michael I think sklearn implements a different algorithm that has non-optimal complexity.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer is related to the question. The question was asking the time complexity of truncated SVD. However, the answer only talks about full SVD.

Comment: @Tan, I wrote about the complexity of the full SVD because the OP gave a wrong estimate of it. For the truncated SVD, have a look on the jin's answer. If $k$ is small, then the complexity of an iteration is roughly $O(mnk)$. If $A$ is ill-conditioned, then you have to do a lot of iterations.

Answer (score 5):

According to the man page of svds, provided by MATLAB, svds is currently based on "Augmented Lanczos Bidiagonalization Algorithm" when it comes to the top-$k$ SVD computation of a large-scale sparse matrix if $k$ is small enough, instead of using the sampling technique answered by loup blanc (you can easily check it by typing edit `svds` in your MATLAB prompt). Please refer to the following paper:

- Baglama, James, and Lothar Reichel. "Augmented implicitly restarted Lanczos bidiagonalization methods." SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing 27.1 (2005): 19-42.

This is considered as an anytime iterative algorithm, i.e., it iteratively computes and updates the target top-$k$ singular triplets until convergence. See Algorithm 3.1 of the above paper.

BTW, it is painful to strictly analyze the time complexity of Algorithm 3.1, since the algorithm is not that intuitive to capture the whole procedure and which part is the main bottleneck of the algorithm.

At a glance, it is considered as
$$
O\big(T(|A|k + k^3 + c)\big)
$$
where

- $T$ is # of iterations,
- |A| is # of non-zeros in the input sparse matrix $A$,
- $k$ is the target number of the largest singular values, and
- $c$ is the other computational cost for each step.

Note that this might be wrong since it is roughly estimated based on sparse matrix multiplication and QR decomposition.

If $k$ is not small enough, svds performs full svd based on sparseQR.

Answer (score 4):

Just as loup blanc's answer. Here is a link to a paper talking about this: http://sysrun.haifa.il.ibm.com/hrl/bigml/files/Holmes.pdf

Comment: This link is no orphan. Can someone post an updated link/ reference?