# Computing smallest singular value of a matrix with explicit error control?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Many good algorithms are out there computing truncated SVD: [What is the time complexity of truncated SVD?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161252).

I am trying to implement some codes to find the smallest singular value of a big matrix $A$. ARPACK can do that via eigenvalues of $M = A^\ast A,$ using Arnoldi methods. However, the "naive" version converges extremely slow when eigenvalues are clustered together.

The shift-and-invert technique speed up convergence a lot. Suppose that we know $\mu>0$ is very close to $\sigma_\text{min}>\mu,$ the smallest singular value of $M.$ Then we can consider $(M-\mu I)^{-1}$ which "pulls" clusters of eigenvalues apart.

The issue is that - this technique requires a **lower bound** on $\sigma_\text{min},$ which I do not know any algorithm to calculate. And frankly, obtaining a lower bound seems a very necessary thing on its own - otherwise how can we be sure that the Arnoldi iterates are accurate? **Does anybody know such an algorithm?**

By the way, the stopping criterion of ARPACK is designed so that we can *"expect"*
$$
|\lambda_c - \lambda_a| \leq \epsilon |\lambda_c|
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the error tolerance parameter, $\lambda_c$ the computed eigenvalue, and $\lambda_a$ the closest actual eigenvalue. This does not help my question because

1. Guaranteeing this stopping criterion makes the algorithm extremely slow, even with huge $\epsilon$ like $0.5.$ Conceptually the inequality above is way stronger than what I need.
2. For such huge epsilon, the inequality does **not** really hold in general in practice when the algorithm halts.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43863/computing-smallest-singular-value-of-a-matrix-with-explicit-error-control Please wait a few days without satisfying answers before cross-posting.